# How can I get .vscode folder and settings.py file on my django project

Tags: django

I was following a tutorial on django .
The tutor was using Mac OS he got the .vscode folder and settings.py in json
But I can’t access that on my windows
I’m using vscode editor

Answer (score 2):

Open the command palette either with the shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+P` or from the menu: `View->Command Palette`. Once the command palette is open, type `Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` and click the option that appears.

This will cause the following things to happen:

1. Creation of the required JSON file (settings.json)
2. Creation of the vscode directory in the explorer window of your IDE
3. Opening of the created settings.json file within the IDE so it could be edited.